# MYSQL, Datatables Group by date with time under Morning, Afternoon & Evening

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatables

Good Day! I want to get an output in Datatables wherein a datetime values **sort the same dates** and put the time whether is it **morning, afternoon or evening** in Datatable's column.

Current Output
[image: Current Output]

Expected Output
[image: Expected Output]

This is my code below

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT *,
                           CASE WHEN TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '11:59:09' THEN DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%h:%i %p')
                           END as morning,

                           CASE WHEN TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '17:59:09' THEN DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%h:%i %p')
                           END as afternoon,

                           CASE WHEN TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '03:59:09' THEN DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%h:%i %p')
                           END as evening

                           FROM tbl_schedule WHERE tech='$tech'

                           GROUP BY DATE(datetime),
                           CASE WHEN TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '11:59:09' THEN DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%h:%i %p')
                           END,

                           CASE WHEN TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '17:59:09' THEN DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%h:%i %p')
                           END,

                           CASE WHEN TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '03:59:09' THEN DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%h:%i %p')
                           END");

foreach($query->result() as $rows){
                
    $json[]=array(
    $rows->tech,
    date("F d", strtotime($rows->datetime)),
        $rows->morning,
    $rows->afternoon,
    $rows->evening
                    
                    
      );
                                
}
```

Comment: you obviously have no "evening" entries (current output) but expect 2 as result? 
can you show the raw data? This seems to be a pure SQL problem...

Comment: in the current output SQL query can't determine a time under evening column, I'm using only a static data in the expected result.

Comment: ok - but it is not helpful if "current" and "expected" output do not base on the same dataset. Here´s a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aed3d4/1/0
What output do you exactly expect?

Comment: based on your fiddle, is there any way to group by all the same dates then align their time based on what they are under (morning,afternoon and evening)?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? Should 06:00 AM and 8:30 AM be one entry? or count them? what if there are 2 "morning" entries for same date? For me it is not clear what output you expect.

Comment: Yeah you are right, problem is what if there are same date entries. I think I'll consider your answer right. Thanks!